# Best way to apply function to element or to list of elements in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

Good time!

What is the best way to make a function that can be applied to one elements or to list of same elements?
For example, I've got such func and I don't want to make map outside.

```
    def setName(self, name):

        if isinstance(name, list):
            return map(self.setName, name)
        else:
            self.names.append(name)
            return
```

For example, I don't know what to expect (string or list) and I need to make function multipurpose.

```
name = "a"
names = ["a", "b", "c"]
obj.setName(name)
obj.setName(names)
```

Are there some other (more optimal) ways to do it?

Comment: python principle: explicit over implicit

Comment: @KatrinaMalakhova it is not very clear, what you want to achieve. Could you provide some sample calls? Best is some working example.

Comment: Not I understand. Thanks to Daniel's comment with which I fully agree. Overloading functions is typical in C++, relying on data types in Java, being readable, flexible and explicit in Python. Keep it Pythonic

Comment: @JanVlcinsky I can get `name = "a"` or `name = ["a", "b", "c"]`. Then I call function `obj.setName(name)` and I want to make it multipurpose

Comment: @KatrinaMalakhova Good, I got it. (better add the sample use into your question, other readers will catch it easier). But is there real need for having it multipurpose? If not, better do not mess up your app and keep it simple and readable for you and your colleagues.

Comment: @Daniel,  JanVlcinsky, thanks. But in my case I can't do explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I can think of is accepting variable number of arguments:

```
def setName(self, *names):
    for name in names:
        self.names.append(name)
```

And now you can call it with:

```
c.setName("Utku")
```

or

```
c.setName("Utku", "Onur")
```

or

```
names = ["Utku", "Onur"]
c.setName(*names)
```